# blurry header image in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

On this test page: http:// www.onebagoneearth.com/ Products-test , where it says "oboe love series", "oboe kind series", etc, when you hover over that text (which is a background-image) in IE7 and IE8(at least on Vista, and also with IETester), the image blurs (not just by being opaque though...that would be the normal hover effect). Why is that?

The same thing doesn't happen on this page with similar CSS: http:// www.onebagoneearth.com /Products . If it's the zoom:1 bit of CSS, I don't understand why it would do that on one page and not the other.

Comment: I'm not getting this in IE8 on Win 7 Aero, what OS are you on?

Comment: For me, on FFX 3.0.15 on Win, both pages behave the same -- they both dim the image slightly, which might be what you mean when you say "blurs"?

Comment: I was using Vista and I meant the actual header text, which is a background-image. It almost looks like the header is split into two layers of the same header image, with one enlarged and opaque behind a smaller non-opaque layer. It looks pretty weird. I clarified this above too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you mean, but on my computer it doesn't blur, it gets a noisy outline of dark gray pixels instead.

It's because you are using a PNG image with an alpha channel, and are applying a filter to it. Internet Explorer doesn't handle this correctly and draws the semi transparent pixels against a solid background instead of the actual background.

When this happens and how it appears exactly may vary from computer to computer, and even on the same computer in different situations. That's why some people experience it and some don't.

Comment: yes! that's it. thank you! I was using a gif before. Are there any fixes apart from just switching back to a GIF (which I believe IE6 doesn't support even with hacks)?

Comment: @Lauren: You could put two versions of each text in the sprite image and switch between them instead of using a filter. IE 6 does support GIF images just fine, so that is also an alternative.